# Bluetoothprofile.ServiceListener : onServiceConnected not called on some devices

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bluetooth

I'm using the HidDevice profile that was introduced in SDK 28.

MinSDK is also 28

On some devices onServiceConnected gets called immediately, on others it never gets called. I haven't seen a pattern on the devices where it works/doesn't work.

This is the line that is "registering" the ServiceListener

```
bluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(applicationContext,serviceListener,BluetoothProfile.HID_DEVICE)
```

And this is the ServiceListener with sample code

```
val serviceListener = object : BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener {

    override fun onServiceConnected(profile: Int, proxy: BluetoothProfile) {
        throw RuntimeException("Not called on some devices")
    }

    override fun onServiceDisconnected(profile: Int) {
        throw RuntimeException("Not called on some devices")
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to find the solution for this?